# Pandas' version of numpy.resize for efficient matrix resizing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, resize

I have a dataframe with two indexes. (Both timestamps but thats probably not relevant).

I need to get out a numpy matrix with shape `(len(first_index), maxlen, num_columns)`.

`maxlen` is some number (likely the max of all of the `len(second_index)`) or just something simple like `1000`.

I can do this with `arr = df.as_matrix(...)` and then `arr.resize((len(first_index), maxlen, num_columns))`. Elements in new rows should be `0` so `.resize(...)` works well.

Is there a simpler and more efficient way to do this within the dataframe? Numpy works just fine but I need maximum efficiency because I have millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within 'Pandas', I would suggest one of the following:

`df.unstack()` which would result in shape `(len(index2), maxlen * num_columns)` following your notation; here `columns` will be stored as a `MultiIndex`.

Alternatively, you can use `df.to_panel()`; `Panel` is a natural Pandas data structure used for 3 dimensions, as in your case. I believe that the shape should be `(num_columns, len(index1), maxlen)`.

You can then fill any `nan`s with `.fillna(0)`.